# Why do i get an error: cant convert '' to a timestamp?

Tags: t-sql, sap-iq

Can't convert '' to a timestamp.

I have a "date_column" (date type) from witch I want to select the top 1 row. I have a procedure that goes trough 10 tables, each table has the column "date_column" and I want to get the top 1 date from each column and create a view based on that date. I tried with a convert statement, and get: cant convert '' to a timestamp error. If i make `@top_date` (date type) i get an cant convert to numeric in the view creation step, so it has to be varchar I think.

```
declare @table_name varchar(100)
declare @top_date varchar(20)
declare @sql varchar(1000)

select @table_name = 'random_name'

select @top_date = (select top 1 convert(varchar(12),date_column,112) from @table_name)

set @sql = ('create view top_view as select * from ' + @table_name + ' where date_column = '''+ @top_date +'''')
execute @sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message pretty much suggests, you can't convert a blank string to a datetime.  I am guessing the below query fetches blank string:

```
select top 1 convert(varchar(12),date_column,112) from @table_name
```

So to get the output, just add this small check.

```
where convert(varchar(12),date_column,112) <> ''
```

**`FINAL CODE`**

```
declare @table_name varchar(100)
declare @top_date varchar(20)
declare @sql varchar(1000)

select @table_name = 'random_name'
```

`select @top_date = (select top 1 convert(varchar(12),date_column,112) from @table_name where convert(varchar(12),date_column,112) <> ''`)

```
set @sql = ('create view top_view as select * from ' + @table_name + ' where date_column = '''+ @top_date +'''')
execute @sql
```